# Use array formula with index match

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula

Is it possible to do an array formula with index match:

e.g:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A3:A),INDEX('SheetB'!E:E,MATCH(A3:A,'SheetB'!H:H,0))))
```

If not, is there a solution that doesn't involve google scripts?

Answer (score 8):

It seems `INDEX` can not return multiple values. It can not be used inside `ARRAYFORMULA`.

The only solution I know of is to use `VLOOKUP`.

See this thread :
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/jVvjbz8u7A8

Example from there :

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP( B12:B15; H2:R32; 1; TRUE))
```

Cheers!

Comment: The problem with VLOOKUP is that it returns the nearest value if it couldn't find the right value

Comment: Not if you pass FALSE as 4th parameter

Comment: Another problem of VLOOKUP is that it only works rightward, i.e. the data must be on the right side of the search key column. To perform leftward searches, the solution is INDEX MATCH...

Comment: Problem is that VLOOKUP is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Use [XLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947?hl=en#)

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(K2:K,R2:R,S2:S))
```

With `XLOOKUP` you can look in one column for a search term, and return a result from the same row in another column, regardless of which side the return column is on

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's specific case, one can actually use `VLOOKUP` for its intended purpose, as a replacement for `MATCH`:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A3:A),VLOOKUP(A3:A,{SheetB!E:E,SheetB!H:H},2,false)))
```

In the general case of trying to use `INDEX` to retrieve multiple values, it can be replaced with a kludge of `VLOOKUP` and `SEQUENCE`:

```
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(A:A,{SEQUENCE(rows(B:B)),B:B},2,true))
```

does what would have been accomplished by

```
=arrayformula(INDEX(B:B,A:A))
```

if the latter worked as OP expected.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old now, but it turns out that INDEX() acts as a defacto ARRAYFORMULA() now.  You can see a fabulous example of this on [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ImGCvls9eDG8omZh9xlHy60nSoq4nvFCtgz2lHOvs60/edit#gid=257331962), which shows how to use a and index(split()) to extract a particular set of text from a cell. The MK.demo tab provides a visual on how the array formula is implied with the INDEX() function.

Nowadays, using a FILTER() or QUERY() function can give the kinds of multiple vlookup the OP was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

im not sure if its gonna work but i did an "IF(ISBLANK() before the INDEX(...) in the ARRAYFORMULA and it went down all the way